# Calculate the residue of $\frac{z^{3/2}\log(z)}{(1+z^{2})^{4}}$ at $z = i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

To find the residue of $$\frac{z^{3/2}\log(z)}{(1+z^{2})^{4}} \qquad \qquad(1)$$ at $z = i$, this is what I've thought:

Express this as a partial fraction: The problem therein is that decomposition of (1) yields something like

$$P_{1}(\frac{1}{z-i}) + P_{2}(\frac{1}{z+i}) + g(z)$$ where

$g(z)$ is an analytic function and $P_{j}(z)$ is as polynomial of finite degree. The $g(z)$ term exists, since (1) is not a rational function, in which case (provided also that the denominator's degree exceeds that of the numerator), the partial fraction decomposition is some summation of $P_{j}$s.

Thus, the inclusion of $g(z)$ makes me a bit nervous to try and solve this.

One could express (1) as

$$ \frac{\frac{z^{3/2}\log(z)}{(z+i)^{4}}}{{(z-i)^{4}}}$$

and then take a third derivative of the numerator, evaluate this result at $i$, and then divide by $3!$, but that is also messy.

And I have no idea how one might express the laurent series of (1).

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: It depends on the $\displaystyle\log$ and $\displaystyle z^{3/2}$ particular branches you choose.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to note that
$$f(z) = \frac{z^{3/2} \log (z)}{(z+i)^4} * \frac{1}{(z-i)^4}=g(z) \frac{1}{(z-i)^4}$$
where $g(z)$ is analytic and non-zero near $z=i$. Thus there is a pole of order $4$.

To find the residue, use the following theorem:

> **Theorem:**
>   If $f(z)$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$, then
>   $$R [ f,z_0 ] = \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{1}{( {m - 1} )!} \frac{d^{m - 1}}{dz^{m - 1}} ( ( z - z_0 )^m f( z )).$$

Thus $$R[f, i] = \lim_{z \to i} \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^3}{dz^3} \frac{z^{3/2} \log (z)}{(z+i)^4}.  $$ There will be some messiness with nested and repeated quotient and product rules, but it's "just" a Calc I problem from here.

Comment: So you're suggesting (I guess the computation is not so messy) that I apply cauchy's theorem to $g(z)$ at $z = i$?

Comment: Yep, that would be my approach---see the edit I just added. A bit messy, but not too bad.

Comment: You need to be a bit more careful.  The functions $z^{3/2}$ and $\log(z)$ are, as you know, not analytic in the plane.  To begin, one needs to cut the plane and establish the Riemann sheet used to define the functions.